# Facebook login worked on localhost but not on hosting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-oauth, http-status-code-401

We have a website that uses Facebook for login, when we run it locally used to work fine. We had a Facebook application with App Domains and Site URL pointing localhost and worked just fine.
However, when we moved into production, we uploaded the site to our hosting and changed the setting in the FB app to match this change.
Now we put "xxxx.com" in App Domains and "https://www.xxxx.com/" in Site URL (it works in both HTTP and HTTPS).

However, when trying to log in I get a 401 error.

I tried every different combination in the FB app that I could think of but still it's not working.
It can't be the code because used to work fine running it in localhost with the app set-up pointing to localhost but I can't make it work on our hosting...

Any ideas?

Comment: by any chance, did you find the solution?

Comment: on FB Developer Console -> Facebook Login -> Settings -> Client OAuth Settings set **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs** this is some link that process the facebook response  to do your logic during clicking to Login with Facebook button on your site

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized 
The error code says it all.

Answer (score 0):

See if setting *App Domains* to blank will help.

Answer (score 0):

If your using an iPhone app go to settings and go to wifi. Click on your wifi. Now go down to renew lease. Click on that. This will solve the problem. I had the same thing happen to me and nobody had an answer. It took me an hour of messing with my phone to find this solution. Hope this was helpful for you.